# What does "[ ]" as output mean while web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape and get the complete table of players, age, value and other columns from a site. I got    "[ ]" as output. What does "[ ]" mean and how can I get the complete table?
This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = ("https://sofifa.com/team/1/arsenal/?&showCol%5B%5D=ae&showCol%5B%5D=hi&showCol%5B%5D=le&showCol%5B%5D=vl&showCol%5B%5D=wg&showCol%5B%5D=rc")
get_link = requests.get(link)
get_text = get_link.text
objBs = BeautifulSoup("get_text", "lxml") 
objBs.findAll("table", {"class":"table table-hover persist-area"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is an empty list, meaning no results were found. The problem is that you passed the literal string `"get_text"` to Beautiful Soup, instead of the actual web page content. You can get the table like this:

```
get_text = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"table table-hover persist-area"})
```